# How to turn a huge list of values into an array of CSV strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a long list of 6000 items, each on a new line, but they have no markup.  How can I wrap each item in quotation marks, and put them all into an array on the same line with a comma separating each item?

I have this on the editor:

```
ORANGES
CARROTS 
ONIONS / SHALLOTS
PEAS.PE
TURNIPS / RADISHES
TOMATOES
```

This is what I would like to see on the console:

```
["ORANGES", "CARROTS", "ONIONS", "PEAS.PE", "TURNIPS", "TOMATOES"]
```

Comment: Why did you skip `SHALLOTS` and `RADISHES`? What tools do you use?

Comment: Because I only want the first item in each row in the created array.

Comment: What tools/languages/whatever do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {                                               # front matter
    printf"["
}
{
    var=var sprintf("%s\"%s\"",(var==""?"":", "),$1)  # build output to var
}
END {                                                 # output var with back matter
    print var "]"
}' file
```

Output:

```
["ORANGES", "CARROTS", "ONIONS", "PEAS.PE", "TURNIPS", "TOMATOES"]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry I meant to add in JavaScript

Comment: Fixed the tags for you. Good luck.